# Web Framework Structure

Tags: apache, webserver, webapi, web-frameworks

There are plenty of **Web** Application **Frameworks** available over the internet. Each of them has its own rich documentation and tutorials. However, there is a lack of information about the structure of these Web Frameworks.

By structure, I mean simple description and graphical representation of relationships and communications between **"Web-Server"** & **"Web-API/ Web-Framework"** regardless of programming languages employed to implement them.

I've done surfing the Net but I have not found any proper reliable info.

Comment: The communication mechanism depends on the specific combination of framework and webserver so your question (which is explicitly generic) can't be answered. There's also a degree of choice in implementation that is up to the developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a hard question to answer, but I will give it a try. So, first, we could ask ourselves:

**How does Web-API communicate with Web-Server?**

The overall structure you can imagine here is that basically the server as a machine has **an open port** on which a **web-server** is listening. The server has **configuration files** which tells it what to do. Basically in new frameworks the server only **sends the request to a corresponding "internal" port** where a web-application is listening, and that **application basically handles the internal logic**. Therefore the Web-Server just "dumbly" sends the data to the set port. This can be altered with the configuration files, where the server can in different ways modify the request.

**What does a Web-Framework consist of?**

Well it completely depends but I would say from a **client side** application (imagine React, Vue, Angular). A **back-end side** application (node, nest, django, flask) a **database** (mongo, maria, postgres). A more "complete" app would have **caching** for example (redis) or **search specific** capabilities (elastic). All in all it depends basically from the specific use case, because you need a different web framework for e-commerce then a B2B app.

Comment: "The server has configuration files which tells it what to do. Basically in new frameworks the server only sends the request to a corresponding "internal" port"  — This makes the assumption that the framework runs as a separate network service to the HTTP server … and it usually doesn't.

Comment: "from a client side application" — Irrelevant. See the diagram in the question. The question is specifically asking about how the web server communicates with Django / Node.js / etc.

Comment: True points. I tried to answer the best I could. If you would answer the question even better Ill appreciate it as well.

Comment: @Quentin It is appreciated if you could help me. I really need to learn about it. Is there any book or any other kind of tutorial that can help me?

Comment: As I said in my comment on the question itself, your question is based on a false premise and can't be answered.

Comment: @Quentin do you mean that **Web-API** Includes the concept of **Web-Server**? Do you mean **Web-API / Web-Framework** is a socket that communicates over a specific port to the internet and it is responsible for the implementation of HTTP, HTTPS, SSL, and ...?

Comment: "do you mean that Web-API Includes the concept of Web-Server?" — Depends on which Web API framework you are using (among other things).

Comment: "Do you mean Web-API / Web-Framework is a socket" — Depends on which Web API framework you are using (among other things).

Comment: @Quentin May I know what do you mean by saying **"your question is based on a false premise"**? Please explain more ... I really need to know about it ...

Comment: Your question: *How do Web Frameworks communicate with Web Servers?* Your premise: *All Web Frameworks communicate with Web servers in the same way.*. They don't. There are a miriade of different ways that communication can be done. (For example, over the years I've written a number of different apps using Catalyst and Apache HTTPD. I've used 4 different mechanisms to connect the App to the HTTP server. And that's just **one** framework and HTTP server combination!) Therefore the question can't be answered.